# Video not always exported to Camera Roll: NSFileManager's removeItemAtPath non-blocking?

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, pbjvision

After reading several tutorials [like this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/?p=13418) and looking at other code exporting videos, we still can't resolve an issue.

Sometimes a new video gets exported to the Camera Roll, and sometimes it doesn't. We can't even reproduce the problem consistently.

The only issue we can imagine is if `NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath` is not a blocking call, but no documentation suggests it's asynchronous, so we assume it's not the case.

Each time, the "Saved video" `println` inside the `writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum` closure gets called, suggesting the video was successfully written to the Camera Roll, but we don't see the video there.

Suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Code:

```
        // -- Get path
        let fileName = "/editedVideo.mp4"
        let allPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsPath = allPaths[0] as! NSString
        let exportPath = docsPath.stringByAppendingFormat(fileName)
        let exportUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(exportPath as String)!

        println(exportPath)

        // -- Remove old video?
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(exportPath as String) {
            println("Deleting existing file\n")
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(exportPath as String, error: nil)
        }

        // -- Create exporter
        let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
        exporter.videoComposition = mutableComposition
        exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exporter.outputURL = exportUrl
        exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

        // -- Export video
        exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
            self.exportDidFinish(exporter)
        })
    }


    func exportDidFinish(exporter: AVAssetExportSession) {
        println("Finished exporting video!")

        // Write out video to photo album
        let assetLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()
        assetLibrary.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(exporter.outputURL, completionBlock: {(url: NSURL!, error: NSError!) in
            println("Saved video \(exporter.outputURL)")

            if (error != nil) {
                println("Error saving video")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**A few suggestion that may help resolve your issue:**

1. Check that the video is valid/compatible with the library as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4089439/51700)

   ```
   if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL])
   {
       [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:videoURL
                                   completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){}
       ];
   }
   ```
2. ensure that the asset url passed back is not nil as referenced [here](https://github.com/objcio/VideoCaptureDemo/blob/master/VideoCaptureDemo/IDFileManager.m)

   ```
   if(error){
       NSLog(@"Error: Domain = %@, Code = %@", [error domain], [error localizedDescription]);
   } else if(assetURL == nil){

       //It's possible for writing to camera roll to fail, without receiving an error message, but assetURL will be nil
       //Happens when disk is (almost) full
       NSLog(@"Error saving to camera roll: no error message, but no url returned");

   } else {
       //remove temp file
       NSError *error;
       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:fileURL error:&error];
       if(error){
           NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
       }

   }
   ```
3. consider using the PHPhotoLibrary instead for exporting video

   ```
   PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
       let assetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideoAtFileURL(videoURL)
       let assetPlaceholder = assetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
   },
   completionHandler: { success, error in
       // check and handle error
       // do something with your asset local identifier
   })
   ```

Comment: hi mark any chance you can help with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704032/swift-video-records-at-one-size-but-renders-at-wrong-size. thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much Mark!