# What are supported video types/codecs/extensions for iPhone 5?

Tags: objective-c, video, avassetexportsession

I am exporting video from `AVMutableComposition` using `AVAssetExportSession`. On every device I tested it works and video is being played, but on iPhone 5 it fails to play exported video.

Some code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"vtvideo-%d.mp4", arc4random() % 1000]]];

self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:comp presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
AVAssetExportSession *assetExport = self.exportSession;
assetExport.videoComposition = vComp;
assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
//assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V;
//assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
assetExport.outputURL = url;
```

After that I export video to Camera Roll using `PHPhotoLibrary`.

I tried to set `assetExport.outputFileType` to three types you see in code and set extension accordingly (mp4, m4v, mov), none of them worked (m4v format wouldn't actually export, it failed on export stage).

So what filetype/extension should I use? Or is the problem in `PHPhotoLibrary`?

Comment: maybe you reach the decoder limit ,try to export a small size video.

Comment: export video using PHPhotoLibrary

Comment: use .mov file extension  use this link may be useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302446/6028575

Comment: @ColeXia its small, not more than 1 minute

Comment: @JaydeepVyas my code makes export just like in your link, using PHPhotoLibrary